# Direction on how to rightly compute a certain expected value.

Tags: probability, random-variables

Dan has 13 different cards, one of which is numbered with a unique number between 1-13. Every day, he pulls a specific card (which he never returns) with a uniform distribution between the cards **left**. If Dan pulls the 13th(or 13rd? I am not native.) he stops. $X_i$, where $1\le i\le13$, is the number written on the card he pulls on the $i$-th day. $X_i=0$ if Dan pulls the 13-numbered card before the $i$-th day. What is $E[X_4]$?

**Attempt:** $X_4\in \{1,...,13\}$. $E[X_4]=13P(A_{13})+...+1\cdot P(A_{1})$  where $A_i$= Dan pulls the $i$-th card in the fourth day. $P(A_{13})={12\over13}\cdot {11\over 12}\cdot{10\over 11}={10\over 13}$. For every other i between 1 to 12: $P(A_i)={11\over13}\cdot {10\over 12}\cdot{9\over 11}={15\over 26}$. Then I have $E[X_4]=13{10\over 13}+S_{12}{15\over 26}$. $S_{12}=1+...+12=78$. I get: $E[X_4]=10+45=55$. However, the options are:

1. $9\over 2$
2. $11\over 2$
3. $70\over 13$
4. None.

I have a feeling it isn't none, which makes me think of ${11\over 2}=5.5={55\over 10}$. Where have I gone wrong? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Now I see I forgot to add the probability of the fourth day card pick.
I shall try again.

Comment: Okay, I computed it again and it is 5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your comments I understand that you are ready with this. I am only offering an alternative route here that avoids calculation of expectation on base of distributions.

Let it be that the card with number $13$ is drawn at day $I$.

Then: $$\mathbb EX_4=\mathbb E(X_4\mid I<4)P(I<4)+\mathbb E(X_4\mid I=4)P(I=4)+\mathbb E(X_4\mid I>4)P(I>4)$$
Here $I$ is uniformly distributed over $\{1,\dots,13\}$, and evidently $\mathbb E(X_4\mid I<4)=0$ and $\mathbb E(X_4\mid I=4)=13$ leading to:$$\mathbb EX_4=1+\mathbb E(X_4\mid I>4)\times\frac9{13}$$

Under condition $I>4$ there are $12$ cards with numbers $1,2,\dots,12$ all having equal chances to be drawn at day $4$, hence: $$\mathbb E(X_4\mid I>4)=\frac1{12}(1+\cdots+12)=\frac{13}2$$ and: $$\mathbb EX_4=1+\frac{13}2\frac9{13}=\frac{11}2$$

More generally for $i\in\{1,\dots,13\}$ you can prove:$$\mathbb EX_i=1+\frac{13}2\frac{13-i}{13}=\frac{15-i}2$$